# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have the following code:

which return me the following exception:

```
ProtocolException was unhandled by user code

The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
```

I tried using the following command (Using `Administrator` in a Command Prompt):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>ServiceModelReg.exe -i
```

and the following appear:

```
Microsoft(R) Windows Communication Foundation Installation Utility
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 3.0.4506.5420]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Installing: Machine.config Section Groups and Handlers (WOW64)

Installing: Machine.config Section Groups and Handlers

Installing: System.Web Build Provider (WOW64)

Installing: System.Web Compilation Assemblies (WOW64)

Installing: HTTP Handlers (WOW64)

Installing: HTTP Modules (WOW64)

Installing: System.Web Build Provider

Installing: System.Web Compilation Assemblies

Installing: HTTP Handlers

Installing: HTTP Modules

Installing: Protocol node for protocol net.tcp (WOW64)

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol net.tcp (WOW64)

Installing: ListenerAdapter node for protocol net.tcp

Installing: Protocol node for protocol net.tcp

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol net.tcp

Installing: Protocol node for protocol net.pipe (WOW64)

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol net.pipe (WOW64)

Installing: ListenerAdapter node for protocol net.pipe

Installing: Protocol node for protocol net.pipe

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol net.pipe

Installing: Protocol node for protocol net.msmq (WOW64)

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol net.msmq (WOW64)

Installing: ListenerAdapter node for protocol net.msmq

Installing: Protocol node for protocol net.msmq

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol net.msmq

Installing: Protocol node for protocol msmq.formatname (WOW64)

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol msmq.formatname (WOW64)

Installing: ListenerAdapter node for protocol msmq.formatname

Installing: Protocol node for protocol msmq.formatname

Installing: TransportConfiguration node for protocol msmq.formatname

Installing: HTTP Modules (WAS)

Installing: HTTP Handlers (WAS)
```

However, the exception is still there!

Appreciate any advices.

(Could it be due to .NET Framework?)

I tried the following:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>ServiceModelReg.exe -i
```

but it return me the following:

```
[Error]Switch '-c' requires a component to be specified for installation or uninstallation. Please specify which components to install or uninstall.
```

Appreciate any helpful advices.

**Added Information**

**Customers.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Services_Customers : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private System.Data.DataTable countryDataTable = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve DataTable from cache
        countryDataTable =
        (System.Data.DataTable)Cache["Countries"];

    }
    protected void GetCountriesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Does cached item exist?
        if (countryDataTable == null)
        {

            CustomersClient customersService = new CustomersClient();
            // Retrieve DataTable from WCF Service
            countryDataTable = customersService.GetCountries(StartingLettersTextBox.Text);

            // Save DataTable to cache
            Cache["Countries"] = countryDataTable;

        }

        // Set GridView DataSource
        CustomersGridView.DataSource = countryDataTable;
        CustomersGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**web.config**

The following code is inside the `<configuration>` in the web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1112/Services/Customers.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" contract="CustomersService.ICustomers" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" />
</client>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What Method do you call?
What is your Binding?

Comment: Please don't stack your title with tags, it isn't necessary.

Comment: @Grumbler85, I have added extra info into my question.

Comment: Since it is an HTTP request, it probably uses POST or GET, but is not allowed to to so, but i can not tell you why. This can be all sort of configuration issues. Probably Google knows lots about that.

Comment: @Grumbler85, I just find out the answer, maybe you can help me to review my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line into your web.config.

```
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
```

The final result will be as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1112/Services/Customers.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" contract="CustomersService.ICustomers" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICustomers" />
</client>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Hm - i was not aware that the error could be something like that.

Comment: @Grumbler85, yeah, I also find it strange. By just adding the code, the error message disappear but a new error message appear as shown in here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314556/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app-web-1btizmpz

Answer (score 1):

The error is Method Not Allowed. I do not see anywhere in your code where you are setting username/password combination on your proxy...  Might be just that?